# Allow to change some text only in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `Text1` and `Text2` in textarea,

```
<textarea id="response" name="response" class="form-control" maxlength="160">Text1. Text2</textarea>
```

I should edit `Text2`, i can't edit `Text1`

Comment: This is not possible with a standard `textarea`. You could possibly hack something together with JS, however it would be unintuitive, a pain to create and maintain and trivial to work around (using dev tools). A better idea is to keep the text which the user is not allowed to edit *outside* of the textarea (simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Lsr15dmc/). You can concatenate them together before submitting the form the server if absolutely required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create virtual textarea. but you can make your max min length in bind method also. with native textarea u can not do it.

```js
$('#result').html($('.textarea').html());
$('.textarea').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    $('#result').html($('.textarea').html());
});
$(function(){   
  $(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {        
    if (objEvent.ctrlKey) {          
        if (objEvent.keyCode == 65) {                         

            return false;
        }            
    }        
  });
});
```

```css
.textarea{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  background:ghostwhite;
}
.editable{float:left}.not{min-width:10px;min-height:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="editable not">Text1 </div><div  contenteditable="false" class="editable ok">Text2 </div>
</div>
<span id="result"></span>
```